# Newline escape sequence not working on php

Tags: php, newline

I have this piece of code and for some reason the escape sequences are not working... what could be the problem?

```
$handle = fopen("TransLoc.txt", "r");
if($handle){
    while(($buffer = fgets($handle)) != false){
        echo "hahahahah\t";
        echo $buffer."\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What are you viewing the file in? Are you using windows?

Answer (score 3):

You probably call this script from a webserver with your browser. In fact the newline appears in the output, but browser don't render them. Look at the source of the page you called and you will see them.
If you want to get a "html"-newline, use `<br/>`. Or if you don't want to send HTML, use

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/nl2br

that function adds a br tag to every newline in the output

try it if you use your function inside an html body

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the header for content type to text/plain having the following line in your code before sending any other data to the browser

```
Header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

If you are just want to send plain text. Otherwise followin @KingCrunch advice.

**EDIT**

@KingCrunch has added the text/plain whilst I was typing in my answer!