# php escape sequence not working

Tags: php, escaping, echo

I just want to echo out some text on the webpage display with a `tab` space before a word.
I have the following codes in php:

```
<?php
   echo "\t\t hello!<br>";
   echo "\t\t", "hello!<br>";
   echo "\t\t"."hello!<br>";
?>
```

I tried all sorts of combinations, but it just won't show the tab spacing before the word.

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello!
hello!
hello!
```

I visited some links like: [Newline escape sequence not working on php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217821/newline-escape-sequence-not-working-on-php) 
but I am not echoing it from a function. I just simply want to echo it out from a `.php file`.

Comment: Reason for the down vote????? Isn't this a proper and legitimate question?

Comment: Using 'tab' with HTML can be tricky... You better use other way of rendering them (http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/qt/tiphtmltab.htm). If you doesn't want to do it, you could try to add a chr(9) at the begining of your echos.

Comment: Look at the HTML source, the tabs are there. `tab   hello!<br>tab  hello!<br>tab  hello!<br>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, but why is it not showing in the browser?

Comment: It's a browser thing. Had you been writing to a file, it would have registered it, same as a `\n` would. If you want to show tabbed in HTML format, you can try `echo "<blockquote>hello!</blockquote>";` or see Nick's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
<pre><?php
   echo "\t\t hello!<br>";
   echo "\t\t", "hello!<br>";
   echo "\t\t"."hello!<br>";
?></pre>
```

I would say you are probably viewing the generated page (html) rather than the page source.

Comment: Um no. If this is the right answer then you clearly didn't google first and have earned that downvote.

Comment: Um it's okay. By the way, I did a lot of googling before posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a tab to html, it is only visible on the source code and then treated as whitespace when rendered in a browser....

just like \n is only visible in page source code and treated as whitespace when rendered... \t and \n are meaningless to html

Comment: Ah..I see.. thanks for the reply here! By the way, can you help to neutralize one the downvote? It is unjustifiable. :(

Comment: Not at all, I googled similar questions, but none mention about how escape sequence is treated in php, and you answered my question, so you earn my vote.

Comment: Ok.... My personal message to those down voting unnecessarily without genuine reason probably because they think a question is too easy, is that they should remember that they were not born with whatever knowledge they think the have now. At least give a reason why you are down voting!